# Change index of a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DF

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 2 | 1 |
| Test2 | 3 | 2 |

What I currently do is the following :

```
DF.reset_index().set_index('b')
```

which give the following output :

| b | a | index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Test1 |
| 2 | 3 | Test2 |

But what if I don't want the column to be named as "index" ?

For example I wish to have the following output : (Replace "index" by "TestName")

| b | a | TestName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Test1 |
| 2 | 3 | Test2 |

Comment: `DF.reset_index().set_index('b').rename(columns={'index':'TestName'})`. There's also `rename_axis` function as well.

Comment: Y i currently use `DF.rename(columns={'index':'TestName'}, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
DF.rename_axis('TestName').reset_index().set_index('b')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the columns manually by doing this

```
df.columns = ['b', 'a', 'TestName']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `index.rename()`

```
DF.set_index('b', inplace=True)
DF.index.rename('TestName', inplace=True)
DF
```

Comment: Is there `dataframe.index.rename()` function?